# How do I use a wildcard with a getopts in a bash script?

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a bash script that I want to take some optional input arguments, followed by either a filename or a file specification containing wildcards.

If I run
   `getopts_problem.sh -td *.txt`
the script happily outputs a list of .txt files in the current directory:

> file is readme.txt letter_to_editor.txt someotherfile.txt

If I run `getopts_problem.sh -td *.ABC`
the script outputs

> file is *.ABC

There are no files in the current directory with the extension ".ABC". For some reason, then, the script interprets "*.ABC" as a filename. How can I get the script to recognise "*.ABC" as a filename expression to be expanded, rather than an actual filename? The code is as follows:

```
# !/bin/sh
doDry=0
doTimestamp=0

while getopts ":dt" OPT;
do
   case $OPT in
      d ) doDry=1 ;;
      t ) doTimestamp=1 ;;
      ? ) echo 'Bad options used. '
          exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
fileList=$@

for file in "$fileList"
do
  echo file is $file
done

exit 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling shell command line wildcard expansion in C or C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617453/controlling-shell-command-line-wildcard-expansion-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 2):

The  wildcard patterns are expanded by `bash` before executing your script. Not the shell that interprets the script, but the one you run it from. And whether it keeps pattern, passes nothing or fails depends on `nullglob`, `failglob` and some such options (see `man bash`).

Also, in `for file in "$fileList"` quotes explicitly tell shell *not* to expand the variable.

Comment: Semantic quibble: the double-quotes allow variable expansion (i.e. replacing its name with its value), but prevent word splitting (i.e. breaking it into multiple words based on spaces).  Net result: the loop runs exactly once, with `$file` set to the entire list of files.  The solution is to use arrays: `fileList=("$@"); for file in "${fileList[@]}"; ...` -- this breaks the file list correctly, even if some filenames contain spaces or other "funny" characters.

Comment: You're right about the quotes around $fileList. I took them out and now there are three lines of "file is" output, listing each .txt file separately. But it still thinks that "*.ABC" is a filename, which is a problem. The workaround I've come up with is to use `[ -e $file ]` in the body of the code to test to see if the file exists. I don't know if this is the accepted way or if it is a giant kludge, but it does work.

Comment: @Kevin, like I said, the expansion of wildcards that match no files is controlled by nullglob, look for it in bash manpage. And also keep in mind that unless you quote it, it will be handled by the shell you use to start the script. Keep that in mind.

Comment: But you also said that the expansion happens in the shell from which the script is run. Doesn't that mean I'd have to set nullglob on the command line before I run my script if I were going to use nullglob to control the expansion?

Comment: @Kevin, why "but"? That's exactly what I meant by "the shell you use to **start** the script". As opposed to the one that actually runs it. Hell, yes, it turns confusing at times, but looks you've got it right.

Comment: Another way to think about this: your script is given some filenames as arguments.  If any of those files don't exist, it should print an appropriate error message and (probably) skip operating on that filename.  It doesn't matter (and your script can't tell) whether that nonexistent file is a result of a user typo, an unmatched wildcard, or whatever.

Comment: OK, Michael and Gordon, thanks for the help. @Michael "why 'but'?". Well, I didn't consider requiring the user always to set nullglob before running my script to be sufficiently user-friendly, so I was hoping for an alternative. I wanted my script to run as simply as "rm" or "chmod", without having to set/unset bash options, etc. Then I realised (thanks to you and Gordon's explanations) that rm and chmod DO act the same way as my script: `ls *.ABC` returns an error saying that no such file exists. So I just have to make my script behave the same way by testing for existence. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, normally executables validate the files passed regardless of the origin. I understand that you didn't want the user to set nullglob, I didn't mean it's really cool to make such a request, I was only explaining the nature of things ;)